# position links at the middle of div bar

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment

I like to do the following using css:

Have a div bar 100pt from top of the page. The div bar will be about 100pt thick. Then at the "middle" of the div bar I like to have the menu options. I got the following so far, however the menu items (links) are not centred:

```
.top_header {
    background-color:#3B5998; 
    height:70px; 
    margin-left:0px; 
    margin-right:0px; 
    top:60px; 
    position:relative 
}

.top_header a, .top_header a:visited, .top_header a:hover, .top_header a:active, .top_header a:focus {
    color:white; 
    font-size:x-large; 
    font-family:Arial
}
```

Comment: Did you mean centred vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to add `line-height`, setting it as the same `height` as the `div`.

```
line-height:70px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/EXqkT/

This aligns it vertically.

Then, if you want to center it horizontally, you can add

```
text-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/EXqkT/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
`text-align:center;'
```

to .top_header.

Answer (score 0):

add `margin:auto` to `.top_header a`

Answer (score 0):

add style text-align:center; to top_header div
http://jsfiddle.net/rajani5022/CpsX2/4/